# Chosen + Dependent Dropdown (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen ( http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ ) and Dependent Dropdown ( http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown) plugins for HTML select forms on my page.

Everything works great except one issue - if 1st (parent) select contains an option which is selected by default when page loads, 2nd (dependent) select is empty, and I need to manually re-select option from 1st select to get options in the dependent select.

According to http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown#options I added "initialize:true" to options list, so it looks like:

```
<script>
// Child # 1
$("#membership_referrer_id").depdrop({
    url: 'membership_new_ajax.php',
    depends: ['client_id'],
    initialize: true
});
</script>
```

However, it didn't help. In case it matters, I use chosen for 1st (parent) select only.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is an old question, I encountered the same problem recently.
My solution was to destroy the chosen selector with `$("#form_field_id").chosen("destroy");` to revert to the native select

Answer (score -2):

The issue is in the CSS of Chosen plugin, try using another plugin(select2) for the other drop down.